# regex substring match with a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a RegEx Patern like

```
    string _pattern = @"\d{4}-\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}";
```

How do I check if a string value belongs to this pattern in full or is part of this pattern.

for e.g if i send

```
        string someString= "0007-08/02/2012";
        Match m = Regex.Match(someString, _pattern);
        //i get a full match
```

but if i send

```
        string someString="0007-"
        //how do i check if this string value matches that pattern and is a substring.
```

Is there any other way of doing it ,other than using  regex.

Thanks,
csk

Comment: Your second example does **not** match the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match any substring of your pattern you has to add '?' in all of the optionals, something like this:

```
string _pattern = @"(\d{4})?(-)?(\d{2})?(\/)?(\d{2})?(\/)?(\d{4})?";
```

This pattern will match any substring of you original pattern.

```
i.e.: 
0007-08/02/2012
0007-
08/02/2012
08/
/02/2012
```

All of that matches the pattern.

Comment: Yes, you're right ( ) arround expression are missing in my answer, i'll edit it.

Comment: This allows for many other matches though. Things like "-/21/" or "2345-/" would match here.

Comment: Cool ! I tried it with '?' and the braces '()' separately.Your solution works.Thanks.

Comment: @LTAcosta to avoid those kind of matches I grouped them as desired like @"(\d{4}-)?(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})?" separating the date part from the first 5 characters.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was going to suggest, but I was unsure of your requirements. I wasn't sure which parts of your string would always occur, and which would only occur sometimes. Like that won't work properly for just 4 digits, since the 4 digits are tied to the -. If you needed to support both cases, you can | all the possible scenarios, or you can probably use an alteration construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
string _pattern = @"\d{4}-(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})?"
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to postfix `someString` with a string known to match the pattern and test it:

```cs
string good = "0007-08/02/2012";
bool isMatch = Regex.Match(someString + good.Substring(someString.Length), _pattern)
```